# LayerDrawable auto change background

Tags: android

```
LayerDrawable bgShape = (LayerDrawable) mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.treasure_box_bg);
if (bgShape != null) {
    ((ShapeDrawable) bgShape.getDrawable(1)).setPadding(0, mScreenWidth / 3, mScreenWidth, mWindowHeight);
    ViewsApiCompat.setBackground(mTreasureBoxView, bgShape);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? All I see is a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ShapeDrawable biggerRectDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    biggerRectDrawable.getPaint().setColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.treasure_box_content_bg));

    ShapeDrawable smallerRectDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    smallerRectDrawable.getPaint().setColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.common_white));
    Drawable[] layers = {smallerRectDrawable, biggerRectDrawable};

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 0, mScreenWidth / 3, 0, 0);
    ViewsApiCompat.setBackground(mTreasureBoxView, layerDrawable);
```

problem solved. bingo.